# How can I send an array of values using javascript to the

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I am making something very similar to the To-do list with jquery. There is one input form, and if user insert value, and press the add button, the value just gets added as the list element.

```
<ul>
    <li>Value</li> 
</ul>
```

The thing is that I somehow have to store the list elements created by user (it can be 1 element, or up to 10 elements) by submitting as a form element. 
What would be the best way to manipulate the submission of list elements?

Should I create multiple hidden input form to store variables? Or should store all the variables in one hidden input form?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you're planning on posting the data or having jQuery submit a JSON string to your PHP.

If you're using JSON (which is what I would recommend) there's no need to get form elements involved. Just have jQuery select all the list items, gather their text content into an array and submit it as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global array and store the values in. Here is an example:

```
<script>
  var items = [];

  // your rest of the code goes here...

</script>
```

***Having scope issue?***

- [Beware of Javascript Hoisting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/)
- [Consider using module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)

***Do you want to retrieve values with subsequent visits?***

- You can use cookies
- If you want to use HTML5, you can use the [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) feature.
- You may even consider something called [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)